# I am not able to use the sqlplus after intalling 11g on redhat 6.7

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

When I execute:

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba
bash: sqlplus: command not found
```

and the bash profile for oracle user is :

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
#added for oracle
TMP=/tmp; export tmp
ORACLE_HOSTNAME=prashant.localdomain; export ORACLE_HOSTNAME
ORACLE_UNQNAME=prod; export ORACLE_UNQNAME
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle; export ORACLE_BASE
ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1; export ORACLE_HOME
ORACLE_SID=prod;$PATH; export ORACLE_SID
PATH=/usr/sbin: export PATH
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:PATH; export PATH
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should sort you out. Remember to login & out again once edited, or do a `. .bash_profile` to source it. Also, make sure it's executable (`chmod u+x ~/.bash_profile` ).

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
TMP=/tmp
ORACLE_HOSTNAME=prashant.localdomain
ORACLE_UNQNAME=prod
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
ORACLE_SID=prod
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH:/usr/sbin:/sbin

export TMP ORACLE_HOSTNAME ORACLE_UNQNAME ORACLE_BASE ORACLE_HOME ORACLE_SID PATH
```

The most glaring error was that you were nuking `PATH` by doing `PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:PATH;` - there was a `$` missing.